# How can I paint only inside of an image without a background

Tags: flutter, dart, paint

The image doesn't have a background and so I thought it should be easy to do... Nope...
I tried stacking the image and the painter, I tried to add a child to the image which is not allowed among other things. Nothing seems to work.

This is a basic painter app and what I need is to be able to paint **only** inside the teeth in the image, **not** in the background

The image:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIhmu.png)

Dependencies:

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  animated_floatactionbuttons: ^0.1.0
```

Code:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:animated_floatactionbuttons/animated_floatactionbuttons.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: WorkOne_8(),
  ));
}

class WorkOne_8 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CanvasPaintingState createState() => _CanvasPaintingState();
}

class _CanvasPaintingState extends State<WorkOne_8> {
  GlobalKey globalKey = GlobalKey();

  List<TouchPoints> points = List();
  double opacity = 1.0;
  StrokeCap strokeType = StrokeCap.round;
  double strokeWidth = 10.0;
  Color selectedColor = Colors.black;

  Future<void> _pickStroke() async {
    //Shows AlertDialog
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,

      //Dismiss alert dialog when set true
      barrierDismissible: true, // user must tap button!
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        //Clips its child in a oval shape
        return ClipOval(
          child: AlertDialog(
            //Creates three buttons to pick stroke value.
            actions: <Widget>[
              //Resetting to default stroke value
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.clear,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  strokeWidth = 3.0;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.brush,
                  size: 24,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  strokeWidth = 10.0;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.brush,
                  size: 40,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  strokeWidth = 30.0;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.brush,
                  size: 60,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  strokeWidth = 50.0;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _opacity() async {
    //Shows AlertDialog
    print('=======');
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,

      //Dismiss alert dialog when set true
      barrierDismissible: true,

      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        //Clips its child in a oval shape
        return ClipOval(
          child: AlertDialog(
            //Creates three buttons to pick opacity value.
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.clear,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  strokeWidth = 3.0;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.opacity,
                  size: 24,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //most transparent
                  opacity = 0.1;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.opacity,
                  size: 40,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  opacity = 0.5;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.opacity,
                  size: 60,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //not transparent at all.
                  opacity = 1.0;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _color() async {
    //Shows AlertDialog
    print('=======');
    return showDialog<void>(
      context: context,

      //Dismiss alert dialog when set true
      barrierDismissible: true,

      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        //Clips its child in a oval shape
        return ClipOval(
          child: AlertDialog(
            //Creates three buttons to pick opacity value.
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.clear,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  strokeWidth = 3.0;
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                mini: true,
                heroTag: "color_red",
                tooltip: 'Color',
                child: colorMenuItem(Colors.red),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedColor = Colors.red;
                  });
                },
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                mini: true,
                heroTag: "color_green",
                tooltip: 'Color',
                child: colorMenuItem(Colors.green),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedColor = Colors.green;
                  });
                },
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                mini: true,
                heroTag: "color_pink",
                tooltip: 'Color',
                child: colorMenuItem(Colors.pink),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedColor = Colors.pink;
                  });
                },
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                mini: true,
                heroTag: "color_blue",
                tooltip: 'Color',
                child: colorMenuItem(Colors.blue),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedColor = Colors.blue;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  List<Widget> fabOption() {
    return <Widget>[
      FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "paint_color",
        child: Icon(Icons.color_lens),
        tooltip: 'Color',
        // mini: true,
        onPressed: () {
          //min: 0, max: 50
          setState(() {
            _color();
          });
        },
      ),
      FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "paint_stroke",
        child: Icon(Icons.brush),
        tooltip: 'Stroke',
        // mini: true,
        onPressed: () {
          //min: 0, max: 50
          setState(() {
            _pickStroke();
          });
        },
      ),
      FloatingActionButton(
        heroTag: "paint_opacity",
        child: Icon(Icons.opacity),
        tooltip: 'Opacity',
        // mini: true,
        onPressed: () {
          //min:0, max:1
          setState(() {
            _opacity();
          });
        },
      ),
      FloatingActionButton(
          heroTag: "home",
          child: Icon(Icons.home),
          tooltip: "Home",
          //mini: true,
          onPressed: () {}),
    ];
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
    final ui.Size logicalSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final double _width = logicalSize.width;
    final double _height = logicalSize.height;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('123'),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: RepaintBoundary(
        key: globalKey,
        child: Center(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              width: _width * 0.75,
              height: _height * 0.75,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
                    points.add(TouchPoints(
                        points: renderBox.globalToLocal(details.localPosition),
                        paint: Paint()
                          ..strokeCap = strokeType
                          ..isAntiAlias = true
                          ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                          ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                  });
                },
                onPanStart: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
                    points.add(TouchPoints(
                        points: renderBox.globalToLocal(details.localPosition),
                        paint: Paint()
                          ..strokeCap = strokeType
                          ..isAntiAlias = true
                          ..color = selectedColor.withOpacity(opacity)
                          ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth));
                  });
                },
                onPanEnd: (details) {
                  setState(() {
                    points.add(null);
                  });
                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Center(
                      child: Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/01_08_01.png',
                        width: _width * 0.7,
                      ),
                    ),
                    CustomPaint(
                      size: Size.infinite,
                      painter: MyPainter(
                        pointsList: points,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: AnimatedFloatingActionButton(
        fabButtons: fabOption(),
        colorStartAnimation: Colors.blue,
        colorEndAnimation: Colors.cyan,
        animatedIconData: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget colorMenuItem(Color color) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          selectedColor = color;
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        });
      },
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
          height: 36,
          width: 36,
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {

  MyPainter({this.pointsList});

  List<TouchPoints> pointsList;
  List<Offset> offsetPoints = List();

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] != null) {
        //Drawing line when two consecutive points are available
        canvas.drawLine(pointsList[i].points, pointsList[i + 1].points,
            pointsList[i].paint);
      } else if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] == null) {
        offsetPoints.clear();
        offsetPoints.add(pointsList[i].points);
        offsetPoints.add(Offset(
            pointsList[i].points.dx + 0.1, pointsList[i].points.dy + 0.1));

        //Draw points when two points are not next to each other
        canvas.drawPoints(
            ui.PointMode.points, offsetPoints, pointsList[i].paint);
      }
    }
  }

  //Called when CustomPainter is rebuilt.
  //Returning true because we want canvas to be rebuilt to reflect new changes.
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}

class TouchPoints {
  Paint paint;
  Offset points;

  TouchPoints({this.points, this.paint});
}
```